# For-loop to dynamically change plot title

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, title

I have 5 variables which want to plot and export in one pdf. However, I have some trouble wiht the for-loop I am running,

```
parC <-list(unit = 100,labelx = "Time",labely = "Time",cols = "black",
            pcex = .01, pch = 1,las = 1,
            labax = seq(0,nrow(RP),100),
            labay = seq(0,nrow(RP),100))

pdf("filename.pdf", onefile=TRUE) 
for (i in RP_values){ # the values that are plotted
  for (j in name) { # name is a list of names, so that the title changes dynamically
  plotting(i, parC, j)
  }
}
dev.off()
```

RP_values = list of values that is plotted
name = list of names to dynamically change the plotting title
plotting = an adjusted version from the plotRP() function of the crqa package. Here I added a main title to the plot.

The code for the plotting() function:

```
plotting <- function(RP, par, x){
  
  if (exists("par") == FALSE){ # we use some defaults
    ## default values
    unit  = 2; labelx = "Time"; labely = "Time" 
    cols  = "black"; pcex = .3; pch = 1; las = 0;
    labax = seq(0, nrow(RP), unit); labay = seq(0, nrow(RP), unit);
  } else { # we load the values that we desire
    for (v in 1:length(par)) assign(names(par)[v], par[[v]])
  }
  
  xdim   = nrow(RP)
  ydim   = ncol(RP)
  
  RP = matrix(as.numeric(RP), nrow = xdim, ncol = ydim) # transform it for plotting
  
  ind = which(RP == 1, arr.ind = T)
  
  tstamp = seq(0, xdim, unit)
  
  par(mar = c(5,5, 1, 3), font.axis = 2, cex.axis = 1,
      font.lab = 2, cex.lab = 1.2)
  
  plot(tstamp, tstamp, type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", main = x)
  matpoints(ind[,1], ind[,2],  cex = pcex, col = cols, pch = pch) 
  
  mtext(labelx, at = mean(tstamp), side = 1, line = 2.2, cex = 1.2, font = 2)
  mtext(labely, at = mean(tstamp), side = 2, line = 2.2, cex = 1.2, font = 2)
  
  
  #  if (is.numeric(labax)){ ## it means there is some default
  #    mtext(labax, at = seq(1, nrow(RP), nrow(RP)/10), side = 1, line = .5, cex = 1, font = 2)
  #    mtext(labay, at = seq(1, nrow(RP), nrow(RP)/10), side = 2, line = .5, cex = 1, font = 2)
  #  } else{
  mtext(labax, at = tstamp, side = 1, line = .5, cex = .8, font = 2, las = las)
  mtext(labay, at = tstamp, side = 2, line = .5, cex = .8, font = 2, las = las)
  
  # }
  
}
```

My problem is instead of 5 plots I get 25, where each plot appears 5 times, but with a different title. If I do not include the "j" part everything works fine, but of course do not have any main title for each plot.

I appreciate any help.

Best,
Johnson

Comment: What is `plotting()?` Please make sure your posted code and sample data makes up a [mcve].

Comment: I added the code for the plotting() function. It is an adjusted version of plotRP() function from the crqa package

Comment: Can't you use `i` as an index to refer to the values in `name`?

Comment: How do `names` relate to `RP_values`? Are they the same length?

Comment: The tip of norie worked as followed:pdf("filename.pdf", onefile=TRUE) 
for (i in 1:length(RP_values)){
  parC <-list(unit = 100,labelx = "Time",labely = "Time",cols = "black",
              pcex = .01, pch = 1,las = 1,
              labax = seq(0,nrow(RP_values[[i]]), 100),
              labay = seq(0,nrow(RP_values[[i]]), 100))
  plotting(RP_values[[i]], parC, x = name[[i]])
}
dev.off()

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. You can answer your own question. Also, `parC` should be inside your `plotting` function.

Answer (score 0):

From your description and comments, it appears you need an elementwise loop and not a nested loop. Consider retrieving all pairwise combinations of `names` and `RP_values` with `expand.grid` and iterate through them with `mapply`. Also, since `parC` depends on `nrows` of corresponding `RP`, have `parC` defined inside function for only two parameters (with more informative names like `title` instead of `x`):

```r
plotting <- function(RP, title) {
    parC <- list(unit=100, labelx="Time", labely="Time",
                 cols="black", pcex=.01, pch=1, las=1, 
                 labax=seq(0, nrow(RP), 100), 
                 labay=seq(0, nrow(RP), 100))
    ...

    plot(tstamp, tstamp, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", 
         xaxt="n", yaxt="n", main=title)

    ...
}

params <- expand.grid(RP_values=RP_values, name=name)

out <- mapply(plotting, RP=params$RP_values, title=params$name)
```